# How to rasterize geojson polygons such that the contour of the polygons appear?

Tags: rasterization, rasterio

I know I can use raterio rasterize to have the outside of polygons as 0's and the inside as 1's, but I Would also like to have the boundaries (as 2's?) so I can separate the different polygons.

Comment: I believe that you must write the polygon boundaries into linestrings and burn them on top of rasterized polygons with another run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such option as far as I know, therefore you need to use some tricks:

option one:

- rasterize your polygon
- convert the polygons to line
- rasterize the line
- add the rasterized line to the existing rasterized polygon (1+1=2)

option two

- apply a negative buffer of 1/2 pixel on each polygon
- rasterize the result
  --> countours and backgrounds will be 0, polygons will be 1

for the geometry operations, you can use [shapely.geometry](http://toblerity.org/shapely/shapely.geometry.html)

Comment: What I did : was ratsterize the polygons, convert the polygon to line, use gdal proximity to comput the distance to said lines, use the rasterized polygons to make the distance negative inside the polygons boundaries, and finally chose whatever interval of distance to be borders. In my case i chose values between -3 and 0.